# How to avoid hanging wget in bash

Tags: bash, wget

I have .sh script that, among other things, wgets currency exchange rates from Google as follows:

```
printf 'Bash: Going to get exchange rates'
echo    
wget -qO- "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=usd&to=aud" |  sed '/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g' > exrates
wget -qO- "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=usd&to=jpy" |  sed '/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g' >> exrates
wget -qO- "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=usd&to=hkd" |  sed '/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g' >> exrates
wget -qO- "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=usd&to=nzd" |  sed '/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g' >> exrates
wget -qO- "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=usd&to=eur" |  sed '/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g' >> exrates
wget -qO- "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=usd&to=gbp" |  sed '/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g' >> exrates

mv /home/stan/perl/2014/scripts/exrates /home/stan/perl/2014/exrates/exrates

printf 'Bash: Got exchange rates'
echo
```

Occasionally script hangs here, however. I don't mind not updating these rates every time it runs, if it hangs I'd like to skip this step altogether, but how?

What should I put in "if" statement to check if wget can fetch data promptly or will take forever? A little more verbosity in wget execution wouldn't hurt either.

Btw, I don't know why wget hangs. Browser opens those pages okay, and same commands run from terminal line by line work, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that it hangs because you have a number of HTTP requests being sent to a single host in a script.  The host in question doesn't like that too much and it starts to block requests from your IP address.

A simple workaround would be to put a `sleep` in between the requests.  You could also make use of a function:

```
getExchangeRates() {
  wget -qO- "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=usd&to=$1" |  sed '/res/!d;s/<[^>]*>//g' >> exrates
  sleep 10   # Adding a 10 second sleep
}
```

and invoke it by passing a parameter to the function:

```
getExchangeRates aud
```

The function could also be invoked in a loop for various currencies:

```
for currency in aud jpy hkd nzd eur gpb; do
  getExchangeRates $currency
done
```

Comment: Somehow invoking this function doesn't work, no parameters get passed or recognized.

Comment: @Stangoesagain There was a typo in the parameter being passed to the function.  Fixed now.

Comment: @devnull Got it, it's either "for currency .. do getExchangeRates $currency" or "for i .. do getExchangeRates $i". Working now. Big thanks

Answer (score 4):

use timeout in wget statement only

```
wget --timeout 10 <URL>
```

timeout is in seconds
and put some 
    sleep in between two wgets

Answer (score 2):

wget has various timeout options.  From the man page

```
   --timeout=seconds
       Set the network timeout to seconds seconds.  This is equivalent to
       specifying --dns-timeout, --connect-timeout, and --read-timeout,
       all at the same time.
```

So you can simply set --timeout, or if you believe it's one of the other factors alone you can set a specific timeout